# Way to keep "userbar" everywhere

Tags: symfony

I'm new to Symfony2 and I'm amazed by it, but still - I have some problems.

I want to have a userbar displaying common user data (login, avatar, unread messages etc.). My problem is: Do I have to use `getDoctrine()` in every controller, or is there a way to keep it in one file and include it somehow?

--edit--

I did use `{# render #}` and now I'm getting... error 101. I did everything [like in here](http://symfony.com/doc/master/book/templating.html) (section Embedding Controllers).

My code:

`routing:`

```
game_shelf_users_userbar:
    pattern:  /User/userbar/{id}
    defaults: { _controller: GameShelfUsersBundle:Default:index }
```

excerpt from `controller:`

```
public function userbarAction() {
        $user = $this->getDoctrine()
            ->getRepository('GameShelfUsersBundle:User')
            ->findOneById('1');

        return $this->render('GameShelfUsersBundle:Default:userbar.html.twig', array(
            'nick' => $user->getNick()
        ));
    }
```

`userbar.html.twig:`

```
<div id="userbar" class="bg grid_5 alpha">
    <a class="grid_1 omega" href="">&nbsp;</a>
    <span class="grid_3 alpha omega">{{ nick }}</span>
    <img class="grid_1 alpha" src="img/users/1.jpg" alt="">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you use twig, use `{# include .. #}`, or `{# render .. #}`

http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/tags/include.html

http://symfony.com/doc/master/book/templating.html

You can (and should) place this in a layout, so you don't need to repeat it over and over again.

Comment: I know about includes, and I use it. My problem is - if I'll have a "game" controller, and include eg. `header.html.twig`, what should I use to have it get informations about user (pulled from database, using `id` from session) without me rewriting the "pull user info" code.

Sorry for making this so unclear, I just can't tell it more straightforward.

Comment: Then you should have a look at `render`.

Comment: @TomekBuszewski I don't see, where you use `render` and also I don't know, what "error 101" should mean. Beside this your `userbarAction()` doesn't have a parameter `id`.

Comment: My mistake, I made error in routing. Error 101 is a http problem with connection reset.